# Cantor Set and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cantor-set

$C$ is Cantor Set. Define $f(x)=−\pi$ if $x\not\in C$ and $f(x)=\pi$ if $x\in C$.
Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at every element of $C$ and continuous otherwise.

The element in Cantor Set can be any point in $[0,1]$, then how does $f$ discontinuous at these points since $f$ is always $\pi$?

Comment: The elements of the Cantor set are not arbitrary elements of $[0,1]$; the set has a very specific structure.  I particular, it is closed, so its complement is open (which is sufficient to show that the constant function is continuous there).  On the other hand, the Cantor set has empty interior, which is how you get at the lack of continuity on the Cantor set.

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor set has empty interior. Therefore, if $x\in C$ you have $f(x)=\pi$, but there are points as close to $x$ as you want which are out of $C$. For each such point $y$, $f(y)=-\pi$. Therefore, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor set $C$ has the property that for any $x \in C$ there is a sequence $x_n$ of points outside of $C$ that converges to $x$ (as $C$ is nowhere dense) and this contradicts (sequential) continuity at $x$. Any $x \notin C$ has an open neighbourhood missing $C$ ($C$ is compact hence closed), and so $f$ is locally constant aroudn $x$, hence continuous.